# Доступ к виртуализированным программам по сети

Tags: виртуальная-машина

Просветите меня, возможно ли такое: запускаем программу на виртуальной машине на одном компе, со второго компа коннектимся к первому компу, при этом отображается не весь рабочий стол, а только окно с необходимой программой?

Comment: Это вы сейчас про удаленный рабочий стол?

Comment: что-то типа этого только с "виртуальными программами". здесь ключевая фраза "только окно с необходимой программой"

Comment: если объяснить проще, то хотелось бы портейбл версию программы работающей на сервере при этом интерфейс которой отображался на рабочем столе клиента

Answer (score 1):

Например, при подключении по RDP зайдите в параметры, там - на вкладку "Программы", чекните "При подключении запускать следующую программу" и введите локальный путь к исполняемому файлу.

Comment: как бы объяснить, это не то что мне нужно...

Comment: @Витя Насонов, ок. программу вы пишете?

Comment: да я пытаюсь..